# How can I install Windows 7 64bit on both MBR or GPT partition?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, mbr, gpt

I want to make a multiboot usb toolkit with different versions of Linux and Windows. I've read that you can only install Windows 7 on MBR and Windows 10 on GPT (tell me if I am wrong).

I found the multiboot programs YUMI and easy2boot. YUMI makes your bootable usb MBR. I am not sure about easy2boot.

What do I have to use for making a multiboot USB toolkit which can boot and install all Windows versions, Linux versions etc. from Legacy or UEFI or both? Also with the possibilty to install on MBR and GPT.

Answer (score 0):

Easy2Boot. There is a website with over 30 YouTube videos, 150 pages, four eBooks and several blogs. That should be enough help for anyone!

Win7 64-bit can be installed in UEFI mode (GPT disk) or MBR\Legacy mode (MBR disk) - not UEFI32.  Win8 and Win10 can be installed in UEFI32 and UEFI64 and Legacy..

P.S. Just remember that Windows 7 is old and does not contain modern USB drivers - so if you are installing on a modern system, then Setup will not be able to find the USB drive and the Windows 7 files.